# On Button Click the selected mails should get tagged with a delete label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

Actually I am trying to achieve bulk delete functionality in gmail by following the below steps

1. First I tried to implement a button in gmail toolbar by naming it as Bulk Delete.

I successfully achieved this functionality as shown below

[image]

2. Now I want to tag the selected mails with common **delete tag**.

   - In this scenario after the selection of mails
   - When we click on the Bulk Delete button
   - The selected mails should get tagged with "deleted" label immediately.

Anyone helping with relevant solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the Gmail API for this purpose. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/ . If you still find any issues you can always ask here

Comment: Write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Incude code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302091/2213940

Comment: What does your 'bulk delete' do? Does it use the gmail-api, or does it just simulate button presses on the screen?